# CORS Not Working (SpringBoot, CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, apache, cors

Im currently developing a small web app that's using the Google Maps API.
The problem I'm struggling with for weeks now is the CORS and I have tried every possible thing that was often suggested by other programmers (modify .htaccess, httpd.conf ; add header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to php and to ajax-request, etc....) but still get a error message that says "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access" (see also [screenshot with  full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t23UZ.png))

When I use the "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *"-Plugin for Chrome everything works just fine, but thats not a solution I'm happy with.

When I open the DevTools and view the headers of my index.php it seems that the CORS headers are there, but the console keeps saying that the 'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin' header is still missing!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G9tW.png

index.php:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if($method == "OPTIONS") {
  die();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<!-- tags and code... -->
```

javascript:

```
function getData(){
  var key = "....";
  var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + $scope.origin + "&destinations=" + $scope.location.address + "|&mode=" + mode + "&key=" + key;

  $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function () { },
            failure: function () { },
            complete: function (data) {
                if (data.readyState == '4' && data.status == '200') {
                    console.log("SUCCESS");
                    console.log(data.responseJSON);
                    //do stuff
                }
                else {
                    console.log("FAIL");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

CIController:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    public function index_options() {
        return $this->response(NULL, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }

}
```

CodeIgnoterApp/application/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

CodeIgnoterApp/system/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

So far I've run this project on my dekstop-PC and on my laptop (XAMPP).
I've used Springboot (a while ago) and CodeIgniter(currently) for the backend.
I also have a version without using localhost/backend-server (using html instead of php of course), which doesn't have ANY CORS problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The https://i.stack.imgur.com/t23UZ.png error says `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api` isn’t including the `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` header in its response.

So that problem has nothing to do with how you’ve configured your PHP code. Your code isn’t setting response headers for that request to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api`. The response headers for that either must be set by `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api` itself, or else you need to send your request through a proxy that adds the headers to the response the browser ends up seeing.

But anyway the root problem is that `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api` doesn’t support requests from client-side JavaScript running in web apps in the way your code is trying to use it.

Instead you need to use the supported [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), the client-side code for which is different from what you’re trying. A [sample for the Distance Matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix) looks more like this:

```javascript
<script>
var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;
service.getDistanceMatrix({
  origins: [origin1, origin2],
  destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
  travelMode: 'DRIVING',
  unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
  avoidHighways: false,
  avoidTolls: false
},…
</script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```